# Unity - Load scene after two seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'am trying to made the scene is change after 2 second. Here's my code:

```
float Czas = Time.time;
if (Czas == 2) {
  Application.LoadLevel("Game");  <-- This is correctly name of the scene
  Debug.Log("Works");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with coroutines for "waiting X" with something like this:

```
void Start()
{
    //Start the coroutine we define below named ChangeAfter2SecondsCoroutine().
    StartCoroutine(ChangeAfter2SecondsCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator ChangeAfter2SecondsCoroutine()
{
    //Print the time of when the function is first called.
    Debug.Log("Started Coroutine at timestamp : " + Time.time);

    //yield on a new YieldInstruction that waits for 5 seconds.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    //After we have waited 2 seconds print the time again.
    Debug.Log("Finished Coroutine at timestamp : " + Time.time);
    //And load the scene
    Application.LoadLevel("Game");  <-- This is correctly name of the scene
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, it really works 

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy approaches you could take.

1.- As explained in the other answer, use an IEnumerator

ex:

```
...
StartCoroutine(ChangeAfter2SecondsCoroutine());
...
IEnumerator ChangeAfter2SecondsCoroutine()
{ 
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
    Application.LoadLevel("Game");  
}
```

Documentation:[StartCoroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

2.- use Invoke

ex:

```
...     
Invoke("LoadLevelGame", 2.0f);
...


void LoadLevelGame()
{
     Application.LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

Documentation: [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)